# Laurent series expansion of $\sqrt{z^2 − 1}$ on $|z| > 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need a little help on the following problem from a past qual.  Any help is great.  Thanks!

Let $f(z)$ be the branch of $\sqrt{z^2 − 1}$ on $|z| > 1$ satisfying $lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f(z)/z = 1.$

(a) Determine the coefficients $α, β, γ, δ, ε$ in the Laurent expansion

$...αz+β+γz^{−1} +δz^{−2} +εz^{−3} +.... $

Comment: Hint: $f(z) = z\cdot\sqrt{1- \frac{1}{z^2}}$, where the branch of $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z^2}}$ is the one with $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: But where is the series centered?  $\infty$?

Comment: It's centered at $0$. It converges in the "annulus" $\{ z : 1 < \lvert z\rvert < \infty\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laurent series on a domain $\{z: r<|z-a|<R\}$ has the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n (z-a)^n$. Here $a=0$ and $R=\infty$.

Unlike with Taylor expansion, taking derivatives at $a$ is not an option. But we can actually look at the problem from the other side, thinking of $\infty$ as the center of the series. The function $f$ has a removable singularity at $\infty$, so it is represented by a (kind of) Taylor series there. But of course, taking derivative at $\infty$ is a special situation: we should think in terms of $\zeta = 1/z$.

In terms of $\zeta$, the function is $\zeta^{-1}(1-\zeta^2)^{-1}$. Since $|\zeta|<1$, the second factor expands into [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series). Returning to $z=1/\zeta$, you'll get the Laurent series.